# Going Back to Grad School

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I am seriously considering going back to graduate school for the PhD and I have two schools in mind. The problems I am facing are: age and I have no letters of recommendation. I do have a MS in Math and have been adjuncting since graduating in 1998. My question, what would be a good strategy for re-inserting myself into graduate school and be able to get funded. TIA.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Academia S.E.! As it stands, I'm of the opinion that this question is [a poor fit for this site](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as it's highly dependent on your own personal situation. I'm voting to close.

Comment: I was 52 when I successfully applied to grad school to do my PhD. It was over 25 years since I completed my master's degree. I used two non-academic managers and a CTO for my letters. If you are planning on Math there is a GRE subject test you could take. Just go for it.

Comment: @Mathin3D You have a lot of questions here. I'm sorry your question got shut down. Perhaps if you asked a less personal situation type of question like, "Is age a factor in graduate school admissions?" and another question like, "What are some options for someone applying to graduate school with no letters of recommendation?" And then you can expand on your situation within your post while having a post that's better fit for a more general audience (ie. others with a similar question.) I wish you the best of luck in your graduate admissions!

Answer (score 1):

One idea that could work is to try and do another masters in math somewhere that has a thesis requirement.  You can use this thesis to study a research problem that is currently being worked on by faculty at the schools that you want to get into.

If you can't do a second masters, how about an independent study somewhere with a prof. that could agree to supervise you for a semester or two?